# Data tables in React: changing state VS updating the DOM manually; data-* attributes VS anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that renders a table of words and their translations based on data fetched from a server. Words are divided into groups, the same word can be present in more than one group. Each group is presented with a separate `<tbody>` tag within the same table.

I have the following REST API route to delete a word from a group: `DELETE /api/groups/group_id/words/word_id`. I want to add this functionality to my React table, so that each table row has a delete button which when clicked sends an AJAX request to the server and if it is successful deletes the row from the table.

The most semantically correct way to delete a row from the table is by updating the component's state which holds the data. Something like this:

```js
this.setState(state => {
  const groups = [...state.groups];
  const groupIndex = groups.findIndex(group => group._id == group_id);
  const group = groups[groupIndex] = { ...groups[groupIndex] }; // for the sake of immutability
  const words = group.words = [...group.words];
  const wordIndex = words.findIndex(word => word._id == word_id);
  words.splice(wordIndex, 1);
  return { groups };
});
```

This in turn will cause the component to re-render. But here comes the problem: re-rendering the whole component just for deleting one table row might be an overkill since `this.state.groups` and the nested word arrays will have to be traversed again (as the `render()` method calls the arrays' `map()` method in order to build the component tree), and after that React's reconciliation will have to be invoked. It seems to be an awful idea if we care about performance.

I know I should avoid it as much as possible in React, but wouldn't it be better in this particular case to turn back to the good old DOM for the sake of performance? Here's what I mean:

```js
deleteWord = (event, group_id, word_id) => {
  fetch(`/api/groups/${group_id}/words/${word_id}`, {
    method: 'DELETE'
  }).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
  }).then(() => {
    // event.target is the delete button that has been clicked
    const td = event.target.parentNode; // table cell
    const tr = td.parentNode; // table row
    tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
  });
};
```

I could still update the state just to keep things synchronized, but with `shouldComponentUpdate()` returning `false` to avoid unnecessary computations.

So my first question is which way should I choose? Maybe I am wrong and the difference in performance is not so critical?

It's not the only question I have, however. I haven't yet said anything about how I am going to retrieve the `group_id` and `word_id` values when one of the delete buttons is clicked. And that's exactly where I have another dilemma.

The most obvious approach would be to add anonymous functions as event listeners while rendering:

```js
const tables = this.state.groups.map(group => {
  const rows = group.words.map(({ _id, word, translations }) => (
    <tr key={_id}>
      <td>{word}</td>
      <td>{translations.join(', ')}</td>
      <td><a href="#" onClick={event => {
        this.deleteWord(event, group._id, _id)
      }}>Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
  ));

  return <tbody key={group._id}>{rows}</tbody>;
});

return <table>{tables}</table>;
```

But I think I should avoid that not to create those functions again if the component ever needs to be re-rendered. So the other option I've been thinking of is adding HTML5 data-* attributes to store `group_id` and `word_id`, and then accessing those via the `event` object. I'd like to know if it's actually a better idea, and that is my second question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use memoization when passing objects, arrays, and functions to components to prevent them from re-rendering if they have not changed. Even though the table as a whole has changed, the individual rows have not, so there is no reason to re-render each row. Re-rendering the table should not cause the rows to re-render if you separate your rows from the table component and/or provide adequate `key`s to them.

You can use `key`s to reference the elements in the mapped array to prevent them from re-rendering when nothing in them has changed. When the table re-renders, it will see that the row with key "value1" has not changed and will thus not re-render that row. It will see the row with key "value2" is missing and will thus strip it from the DOM. It will see the row with key "value3" has not changed and will thus not re-render that row.

Using an anonymous function in your example causes that function to be re-created each render. This causes a new pointer to be passed as a prop to that element, causing that element to re-render. You should memoize your inline functions, objects, and arrays.